# Sparkjava framework github repositories

Tags: java, github, spark-java

Is there any public github repositories with an example of how to use spark java in a real projects?

Answer (score 0):

You may like to have a look on the following github repository. This has an example code as we,ll.

The link to the github is  : https://github.com/apache/spark

The file that has the example code resides here : https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java

See if this helps.

Comment: I think the question referred to [http://sparkjava.com](http://sparkjava.com), the web framework. Not the Apache system for Big Data.